# Order list<T> on a numerical base

Tags: c#, generics, sql-order-by, icomparer, icomparablet

i am using this code to order a list descending on numerical base

```
ItemsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Views, new IntComparer());

public class IntComparer : IComparer<long>
{
    IComparer<long> Members;

    public int Compare(long x, long y)
    {
        return Math.Sign(x - y);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't order at all :S any help plz

Comment: What do you mean numerical base ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Enumerable.OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916.aspx) is part of LINQ.

So it is not modifying the list, but it is creating new one. Use

```
ItemsList = ItemsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Views, new IntComparer()).ToList();
```

or something similiar.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534861.aspx#Y1185
It seems that this method doesn't update the list, so you need to store the result.

```
List aList = ItemsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Views, new IntComparer());

public class IntComparer : IComparer<long>
{
    IComparer<int> Members;

    public int Compare(long x, long y)
    {
        return Math.Sign(x - y);
    }
}

ItemsList = aList;
```